# Making edge list from Pandas Data frame by matching row values and put into edgelist

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to run a community detection algorithm using a dataset stored in a pandas dataframe, to do this I need to make an edgelist from this dataset to be put into a graph. I need this edgelist to consist of rows with matching column value. 
The dataset consists of 19 columns and over 2000 rows I need to make edges between each column row that have matching values. 
For example if the dataset were

```
id   col1 col2 col3 
 1    12    10   20
 2    14    10   19
 3    12    10   9
```

Then there would be the following edges

```
row1 col1, row2 col1
row1 col2, row2 col2
row1 col2, row3 col2
row2 col2, row3 col2
```

I've tried a couple of ways but none seem to work quite the way I want the closest I got was using the following code:

```
#define edges as column rows that have matching data
edges = set()
for col in dataset:
    for _, data in dataset.groupby(col):
        edges.update(itertools.combinations(data.index, 2)) 

#create empty graph
G = nx.Graph()
#add index number as node to graph
G.add_nodes_from(dataset.index)
#add edges created 
G.add_edges_from(edges)

#uses community library to work define best partition that maximise modularity (Louvain Algorithm)
partition= community.best_partition(G)

#create graph from the results of the partition
size = float(len(set(partition.values())))
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
count = 0.
for com in set(partition.values()) :
    count = count + 1.
    list_nodes = [nodes for nodes in partition.keys()
                                if partition[nodes] == com]
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, list_nodes, node_size = 20, cmap=plt.cm.RdYlBu,
                                node_color=list(partition.values()))
plt.show()
```

Comment: What isn't working for you? Seems like an appropriate way to get your edges.

Comment: Indeed it looks as though it should work yet when the graph is displayed the nodes are all the same colour which shouldn't be the case. Each community of nodes should be a different colour I figured I must have done something wrong when creating the graph. The edges was the only part I could think of to be incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Let the data frame can be read into the following format, then

```
    df = id  col1  col2  col3 
         1    12    10    20
         2    14    10    19
         3    12    10    9
```

We can create a new dataframe according to the following:

```
    edge_list_df = pd.melt(df,id_vars='id', value_name='Numbers', var_name='cols').query('id != cols')
```

edge_list_df will have something like this:

```
       id   cols  Numbers
    0   1   col1       12
    1   2   col1       14
    2   3   col1       12
    3   1   col2       10
    4   2   col2       10
    5   3   col2       10
    6   1   col3       20
    7   2   col3       19
    8   3   col3       9
```

Hope this helps :)